# Why doesn't psql show my data even though pgadmin has it

Tags: postgresql, psql

[image]

I have a database called `demo` which has 4 tables.

I run `psql -U user1 demo` and am able to login, but I cannot see any of the tables.

One of the table is `student`. I can surely just reimport the data all again, but why wouldn't it show here?

My `user1` is full admin and has access to everything, so I don't think it's a user related issue.

All my tables are also owned by `user1`, if this makes any difference.

I am **not** using a VM, everything is on my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `university` schema to your `search_path`.  Either you can `SET search_path TO ...` or add it to `search_path` in `postgresql.conf`.  Otherwise, you could perform your `SELECT` with fully-qualified table name:

```
SELECT * FROM university.student;
```

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Comment: you don't really need to change the search_path in `postgresql.conf` it's probably better to change it for the user `alter user set  search_path =...`

Comment: Thanks I did : `alter role user1 set search_path=university;`, connected again, and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Your tables are located in the schema `university` you need to use:

```
select *
from university.student;
```

To list the tables in that schema, use: `\d university.*`